# PyCharm: "No module named configobj" when under RemoteDebugServer

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev

I can debug my scripts in local interpreter mode in Pycharm,
but when a remote debugging environment for python is configured via:

1. `import pydevd`
2. add `pycharm-debug-egg` in path
3. etc

I get `No module named configobj`.

Module `Configobj` is installed in all my local python environments, so the question is: which python interpreter/environment is used when runnng
under `PYDEVD`? Where should I install `configobj`?

Comment: it seems the problem is related to pycharm/pydev, since web debugging the same script through python simple server is working (module configobj is found)

Answer (score -1):

[SOLVED] 
Ok, 
  since in my situation the server is apache2/wsgi, when remote debugging is activated the python environment is the one used by apache/wsgi and specified in the WSGIDaemonProcess directive

Bye

Comment: Nope. this is not really helpful.